# Simple posix server can't set UILabel from loop

Tags: ios, c, sockets, posix

I'm trying to add a posix socket server to my iOS app that will allow a TCP connection and writes the buffer to a UILabel object as a test.

I can get it to work...once.  Then it finishes and closes the connection.  Ok, easy fix, I'll just put it in a loop.  Now whenever I put the exact same code in a loop, it won't update the UILabel for some reason.  I don't actually need it to be able to update the UILabel, it was just a test to make sure the server was working.......but it's making me nervous.  I take it out of the while loop, it works, I put it back in, and everything but the UILabel setText call work.

Also, two other small questions: I'm having trouble figuring out how to exit the loop after a client disconnects, and I'm not sure how to correctly close the ports when I exit, I have to keep changing the port number because it can't bind.

-(void)viewDidLoad

```
    NSThread *listenThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(createPosixServer) object:nil];
    [listenThread start];
```

-(void)createPosixServer

```
    //declarations
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    NSString *nsbuffer;

    //bind and listen on socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error while calling socket()");
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 1818;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR on binding");
    }
    listen(sockfd, 5);
    NSLog(@"Begin listen loop");
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR on accept");
    }
    while(true) {
        bzero(buffer,256);

        n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
        if (n < 0) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR reading from socket");

        }
        if (n > 0) {
            nsbuffer = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            [_lblStatus setText:nsbuffer];
            NSLog(@"You sent %@", nsbuffer);
        }

        NSLog(@"Finished listen loop");
        sleep(1);
    }
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    NSLog(@"Socket closed");
```

Comment: Forgot to include the code yesterday.  Was really fried after a long coding day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createPosixServer` is running on a background thread.  It is never safe to update the UI from a background thread.  UIKit will sometimes work, sometimes just ignore you.  You need to dispatch the call to update the label onto the main thread, something like this:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    weakSelf.lblStatus.text = nsbuffer;
});
```

To answer the side question: when a client disconnects you want to close the socket that you accepted for that connection (your `newsockfd`) but you don't want to close your listener `sockfd` until you are tearing down the whole service.

To exit the loop, simply do this:

```
if (n < 0) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR reading from socket");
    break;
}
```

Though you probably want to check `errno` in that block too because you're probably going to want different behavior depending on the error.

Remove the `sleep(1)`, that is doing nothing good for you.  The `read` call will block, there's no need to sleep.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I suspected that updating the UI from a separate thread was a no-no, but I wasn't sure how to mix C and Objective-C to make the call correctly.  And I was closing it backward it looks like, I thought the `sockfd` object would be first to go since I created it last.  It never occurred to me that that was the part I was missing.  And what did you mean that the `read()` call will block?  The `sleep()` call was to make sure that I don't overload the processor checking it a million times per second.  I don't need that at all?